# AWS EC2 how to connect without key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a fresh RHEL EC2 Instance and select the option to connect without a keypair.

> Instance is not associated with a key pair This instance is not
>   associated with a key pair. Without a key pair you will need to log
>   into this instance using a valid username and password combination.

How can I make a user and password now to connect to my instance using SFTP?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this creating new users and passwords for each user you want to be able to access the instance. However, to create the users you will need to access the instance, so you will need to create the instance and attach it to a key, or create a custom AMI with username/password credentials.

Them, you can just create your users following [these steps](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-password-login/)